# ¿Cómo eliminar ciertos elementos de una lista implementando Lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lista, lambda

Cuento con un formulario el cual realizo una consulta por diferentes filtros. Un ejemplo de filtro:

```
protected void ddlAreaServicio_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cargarDDLTipoReclamo(Convert.ToInt64(ddlAreaServicio.SelectedValue));

        if (Convert.ToInt64(ddlAreaServicio.SelectedValue) != -1)
        {
            List<v_ConsultarReclamo> lstReclamo = (List<v_ConsultarReclamo>)Session["lstReclamo"];

            if (lstReclamo == null || lstReclamo.Count == 0)
            {
                webService = new WebServiceDC();
                Session["stReclamo"] = webService.SelectReclamo("arServ_ID = " + Convert.ToInt64(ddlAreaServicio.SelectedValue));

                JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Session["lstReclamo"] = jsSer.Deserialize<List<v_ConsultarReclamo>>(Session["stReclamo"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Session["lstReclamo"] = lstReclamo.FindAll(x => x.arServ_ID == Convert.ToInt64(ddlAreaServicio.SelectedValue));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session["lstReclamo"] = null;
        }

        gvConsultaReclamo.DataSource = null;
        gvConsultaReclamo.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Tomando este código, si yo realizara el filtro por otros campos y este, y luego deseo deseleccionar éste último (`ddlAreaServicio.SelectedValue = -1`), `Session["lstReclamo"]` queda en `null` habiendo sacado los filtros anteriores..

¿Hay alguna forma de que al deseleccionar elimine únicamente los elementos que deseo, sin entorpecer el filtro que venía haciendo?

Comment: No lo creo. Yo lo que suelo hacer en estos casos es crear un método para todos los filtros `AplicarFiltros`, llamar a ese método donde sea necesario (en tu caso, cuando se seleccione un item de cualquier ddl asociado a filtros) y ahi revisar todos los criterios para generar la consulta correcta.

Comment: Hola @Pikoh gracias por tu respuesta, podrías mostrarme alguna parte de como realizas esto que me decís? Saludos

Comment: Es que depende mucho de los filtros que tengas. Pero la idea es esa, que siempre que se seleccione una opcion de un filtro se llame al mismo método, y se filtre por todos los criterios seleccionados. Depende de como sean puede ser sencillo o complicarse bastante, sobre todo al tratarse de lambdas que no te permiten simplemente componer el filtro con un string. Lamentablemente no tengo ahora disponible ningun ejemplo para poder mostrarte, a ver si algun otro usuario de la comunidad tiene algo para mostrarte.